# visual studio for mac unable to create ipa file

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ipa, visual-studio-mac

I am using visual studio for mac Community Edition on MAC Virtual Machine. I have created a webView iOS application with iPhone Simulator. In project options, I have checked the box for creating ipa file but actually I am not able to find ipa file for the project in directory

> bin->iPhoneSimulator->Release

Please help me.

Screenshots are attached.

[image: Screenshot 1 - Project Options]

[image: Screenshot 2 - Project Directory]

Comment: Please consider to include any images directly to your question via this [option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). Images uploaded to third party services might be deleted after a certain period of time, which obsoletes your question.

Answer (score 0):

- Select a Release Configuration
- Select a Device
- Perform a `Build / Archive for Publishing`

[image]

Comment: Sir, i have select Release option
then select a device like iPhone 5s then i got error messaage
"Your configuration doesn't target a valid iOS Device"
and when i choose "Generic Device" it throws an error "you need to archive an application project first in order to sign and publish it "

Comment: as i already told you when i select "Generic Device" it display an error. "you need to archive an application project first in order to sign and publish it "